# Stored Procedure Hit Counter

Tags: stored-procedures, counter

I have a table with 3 column's in a table on a MS SQL 2008 Database

```
ID
ToolID
Count
```

Can someone toss me a script that will create a stored procedure that accepts the param ToolID and increases its value by 1?

All of my efforts have failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE IncrementToolCount
(
   @ToolID  int
)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON

UPDATE Tools_Usage SET [Count]=ISNULL([Count],0)+1 WHERE ToolID=@ToolID

GO
```

Comment: Count is what I wanted to update. And it seems to run fine, but it doesnt seem to increase the value, I think that's my LINQ thou. Table name is 'Tools_Usage'

Comment: If Count is currently null, then this script won't work.  Set a default on the Count field to 0.

Comment: @Tyler, I'm not sure if LINQ will know to refresh its local value after you run this procedure.  @Chris Lively, thanks, I've corrected the handling of NULL values.